# How to implement branching in bison-based interpreter?

Tags: virtual-machine, bison, interpreter, flex-lexer

Now I develop a virtual machine. Bytecode interpreter uses flex and bison.
Here is some code for example:

```
some:
add r0 4 4
jmp some
```

My question is: how to handle jmp instruction? 
Can I ask the bison to go back to a label, continuing the analysis?

I develop interpreter of bytecode, not compiler...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186142/goto-label-in-the-same-loop-in-bison/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't make bison go back. You usually Bison to parse the code and generate some kind of intermediate representation. Like an AST or bytecode. Then you execute that in a separate step.

So in your case, since you're parsing an assembly language for a bytecode format, it makes sense to translate that into actual bytecode. That is when your parser sees "add r0 4 4", all it should do is append the corresponding sequence of bytes to an array containing your bytecode. Then after the parser creates this array, you can pass it to a function that actually executes the bytecode.

It would probably also make sense to split these two steps into two separate programs: an assembler that turns a source file into a binary bytecode file, and a bytecode interpreter that reads a bytecode file and executes it. The latter would not need to use Bison at all, just read the bytes and `switch` on them.

Comment: Oh, I understood! 
First we translate a text version of the bytecode in a real binary bytecode (assembler), and then execute it by separate program/algorithm.

English is not my native language... Are there any other names of "intermediate bytecode", "actual bytecode"?

Comment: @Saitei The textual version is usual referred to as "assembly code/language" or "assembly" (just like the textual versions of real machine languages are) and the binary version just as "bytecode".

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot!